# Fill a Vlocity matrix with data using Apex

Tags: apex, vlocity, matrix, omnistudio

I have a use case where i want to create and fill a matrix version from Apex.
This matrix is a versioned matrix like: https://docs.vlocity.com/en/Ways-to-Create-a-Standard-Calculation-Matrix.html

Is there a way to do this? Reading from the documentation I don't get high hopes, as it's not described.
I can make a matrix version with Apex, just by inserting the SObject, but filling it with data, that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a code snippet where I am updating Matrix rows of the currently active Matrix Version, which is usually the version for which Start Date is less than the current date and End Date is either greater than the current date or is blank. If we have multiple versions matching the date criteria, then Vlocity uses the version having the highest priority value.

```
//Fetching the Matrix Id using Matrix Name 
List<vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrix__c> matrixList = [SELECT Id FROM vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrix__c WHERE Name = :Name];

//Fetching the required Matrix Version using Matrix Id
List<vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrixVersion__c> versionList = [SELECT Id FROM vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrixVersion__c WHERE vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrixId__c = :matrixList.get(0).Id AND vlocity_ins__StartDateTime__c <= Today AND (vlocity_ins__EndDateTime__c >= Today OR vlocity_ins__EndDateTime__c = null) ORDER BY vlocity_ins__Priority__c DESC LIMIT 1];

//Fetching Matrix Rows using Matrix Version Id 
List<vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrixRow__c> rowList = [SELECT vlocity_ins__InputData__c FROM vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrixRow__c WHERE vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrixVersionId__c = :versionList.get(0).Id];

//Iterating over Matrix Row records 
for(vlocity_ins__CalculationMatrixRow__c row : rowList){

    //Condition to check if current row is not a Header Record 
    if(!row.Name.equals('Header')){

        //Initializing InputData map
        Map<String, Object> InputData = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(String.valueOf(row.vlocity_ins__InputData__c));

        /*
        Your logic to modify Input Data
        */

        //Updating row Input Data
        row.vlocity_ins__InputData__c = JSON.serialize(InputData);
    }
}

//Updating Matrix Rows
update rowList;
```

> NOTE : Input Data, Output Data and Output Data Long are all Text Area
> fields, hence we can't add filter for these values in SOQL query

Comment: Hello Swapnil, this post is an improvement on your first post, which was only a link to your blog. However, if you link to your blog in every single post here you are still likely to get flagged as a [spammer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Consider simply linking to your blog in your bio, and avoid linking to it elsewhere.